# Shutdown Interbase Database from Delphi

Tags: delphi, interbase

Using the **TIBConfigService** I'm attempting to shutdown an Interbase database using its **ShutdownDatabase** method like so:

`ibConfig.ShutdownDatabase(Forced, 0);`

This ends up with an error, **"Invalid Service Handle".**

Setting the **Active** property on the control is successful and other methods on the **TIBConfigService** such as **SweepDatabase** work as expected.

How can I resolve the **"Invalid Service Handle"** error?

Comment: `Invalid Service Handle` is an Interbase error from what I can see. Did you set `Active` to true before you tried `ShutdownDatabase`? What does the `Handle` look like before you call `ShutdownDatabase`?

Comment: Yes, I set Active to true prior to calling ShutdownDatabase and it performs the attach call (isc_service_attach) without issue and the handle pointer has a value afterwards.